# JSON Lint says it's valid but JSON.parse throws error

Tags: javascript, json

I have simple JSON that I need to parse to object. Strangely it doesn't work even though if I copy and paste my JSON string to JSONLint (http://jsonlint.com/) it will show that it's valid.

```
var string = '{"token":"9eebcdc435686459c0e0faac854997f3","email":"201403050007950","id":"13","updated_at":"2014-03-05 10:34:51","messageguides":"[{\"name\":\"Un-named Messaging Guide 1\",\"pages\":[\"sustainabilitydirectors\",\"marketingnbusinessdevelopmentdirectors\"],\"date\":1394015692958}]"}';

var obj = JSON.parse(string); // Unexpected token n

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: You have JSON inside your JSON ?

Comment: I think you need to to `double escape` your escape marks. So `\\"name\\"` instead of `\"name\"`.

Comment: Andy is right here. But you should really review how you generate the JSON, there's no reason to pass an array as a JSON string inside the JSON.

Comment: @dystroy it's not my code, I just need to fix it. :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `\` characters in the data are treated as JSON escape characters when you parse the raw JSON.

When you embed that JSON inside a JavaScript string, they are treated as *JavaScript* escape characters and not JSON escape characters.

You need to escape them as `\\` when you express your JSON as a JavaScript string.

---

That said, you are usually better off just dropping the JSON in to the JavaScript as an object (or array) literal instead of embedding it in a string and then parsing it as a separate step.

```
var obj = {"token":"9eebcdc435686459c0e0faac854997f3","email":"201403050007950","id":"13","updated_at":"2014-03-05 10:34:51","messageguides":"[{\"name\":\"Un-named Messaging Guide 1\",\"pages\":[\"sustainabilitydirectors\",\"marketingnbusinessdevelopmentdirectors\"],\"date\":1394015692958}]"};
```